# Нужно ли освобождать память?

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно ли освобождать блок памяти, на который указывает указатель `maze` в методе `generateMаze()`, с помощью функции `free()`. Использую метод `cleanMemory()` для освобождения памяти, но нужно ли это? Если `maze` - локальная переменная, то память будет выделятся в стеке и при выходе из функции будет происходить очистка памяти? Множество указателей в программе, не пойму, где нужно, а где не нужно применять `free()`. Проясните пожалуйста этот момент.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "functions.h"

//цілочисленна змінна для збереження кількості напрямів (вправо, вліво, вгору, вниз)
int amountOfDirections = 4;
//ітераційні змінні для для проходження в циклі по елементах матриці
int i, j;

void printWarningAndExit() {
    puts("Memory allocation failure");
    exit(1);
}

void printMaze(int **maze, int width, int height) {
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == 0)
                /*
                    встановлення кольору тексту в консолі
                    кожному кольору відповідає числове значення, 
                    яке передається функції другим аргументом
                */
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 12);
            else if (maze[i][j] == 2)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 14);
            else if (maze[i][j] == 5)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 28);
            else {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 26);
            }
            printf("%2d ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //повернення кольору тексту до білого на чорному фоні після виведення матриці в консоль
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp;
    //записуємо значення, яке зберігається за адресою, на яку вказує а
    //у змінну temp
    temp = *a;
    //записуємо за адресою, на яку вказує вказівник а, значення, 
    //котре міститься за адресою, на яку вказує вказівник b
    *a = *b;
    //записуємо за адресою, на яку вказує вказівник b, значення, 
    //котре зберігається у змінній temp --> "старе" значення *a
    *b = temp;
}

void shuffle(int *array, int size) {
    //призупиняємо роботу програми на 1150 ms 
    Sleep(1150);
    /*
        встановлення в якості бази генератора випадкових чисел поточний час
        цей прийом використовується для того, щоб при різних запусках генератора
        була кожен раз різна база генератора і відповідно різні випадкові значення
        через те, що srand() буде оновлювати базу генератора кожну секунду, а функція
        shuffle() буде викликатися КІЛЬКА РАЗ в секунду, використовуємо sleep() на 1 секунду
        щоб гарантувати різні випадкові значення кожен раз при виклику rand() в shuffle()
    */
    srand(time(NULL));

    //ітеруємося від кінця масиву до його початку 
    for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //отримуємо випадкове значення від 0 до i включно
        j = rand() % (i + 1);
        /*
            міняємо місцями елемент під відповідним до поточної ітерації індексом
            та елемент під випадковим індексом
            наприклад маємо масив [1, 2, 3, 4]
            розглядаємо елемент з індексом 2 --> 3
            генеруємо випадкове значення від 0 до 2 включно
            тобто можемо переставити елемент з будь-яким зліва чи залишити елемент 
            на своєму місці
        */

        swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }

}

int* generateRandomDirections() {
    //створюємо 4-елементний одномірний масив
    int *randoms;
    if ((randoms = (int*)calloc(amountOfDirections, sizeof(int))) == 0) {
        printWarningAndExit();
    }
    //заповнюємо його значеннями [1, 2, 3, 4]
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDirections; i++)
        randoms[i] = i + 1;
    //перемішуємо їх
    shuffle(randoms, amountOfDirections);
    //повертаємо масив
    return randoms;
}

void recursion(int **maze, int width, int height, int raw, int col) {
    printf(".");
    //отримуємо масив з 4 значень {1, 2, 3, 4}, розташованих у ньому у випадковому порядку
    int* randDirections = generateRandomDirections();
    //аналізуємо кожен напрямок
    for (i = 0; i < amountOfDirections; i++) {
        switch (randDirections[i]) {
        case 1: //UP
            if (raw - 2 <= 0) {
                /*
                    якщо немає елемента на 2 рядка вище над поточним
                    або ж він лежить на верхньому "кордоні" лабіринту
                    (що недопустимо, адже при генерації утвориться кілька входів)...
                */
                continue;
            }
            //якщо елемент, котрий на 2 рядка вище над поточним, рівний 1(стіна)
            if (maze[raw - 2][col] == 1) {
                //то заповнюємо нулями 2 ячейки лабіринту вертикально вгору від поточної 
                maze[raw - 2][col] = 0;
                maze[raw - 1][col] = 0;
                //викликаємо цю ж функцію для елементу, котрий на 2 рядка вище від поточного
                //(тепер він стає поточним)
                recursion(maze, width, height, raw - 2, col);
            }
            break;
        case 2: //Right
                /*
                якщо немає елемента на 2 стопця правіше від поточного
                або ж він лежить на правому "кордоні" лабіринту
                (що недопустимо, адже при генерації утвориться кілька входів), 
                або ж елемент знаходиться на верхньому "кордоні"(наприклад, якщо
                розглядаємо вхід, то ми не можемо зробити коридор вправо від входу)...
                */
            if ((col + 2) >= width - 1 || raw == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            //якщо елемент, котрий на 2 стопвця правіше від поточного, рівний 1(стіна)
            if (maze[raw][col + 2] == 1) {
                //то заповнюємо нулями 2 ячейки лабіринту горизонтально вправо від поточної 
                maze[raw][col + 2] = 0;
                maze[raw][col + 1] = 0;
                //викликаємо цю ж функцію для елементу, котрий на 2 стопці правіше від поточного
                //(тепер він стає поточним)
                recursion(maze, width, height, raw, col + 2);
            }
            break;
        case 3: //Down
                /*
                якщо немає елемента на 2 рядка нижче під поточним
                або ж він лежить на нижньому "кордоні" лабіринту
                (недопустимо, утвориться кілька виходів після різних рекурсивних викликів)...
                */
            if ((raw + 2) >= height - 1)
                continue;
            //якщо елемент, котрий на 2 рядка нижче під поточним, рівний 1(стіна)
            if (maze[raw + 2][col] == 1) {
                //то заповнюємо нулями 2 ячейки лабіринту вертикально вниз від поточної 
                maze[raw + 2][col] = 0;
                maze[raw + 1][col] = 0;
                //викликаємо цю ж функцію для елементу, котрий на 2 рядка нижче від поточного
                //(тепер він стає поточним)
                recursion(maze, width, height, raw + 2, col);
            }
            break;
        case 4: //Left
                /*
                якщо немає елемента на 2 стопця лівіше від поточного
                або ж він лежить на лівому "кордоні" лабіринту
                (що недопустимо, адже при генерації утвориться кілька входів),
                або ж елемент знаходиться на верхньому "кордоні"(наприклад, якщо
                розглядаємо вхід, то ми не можемо зробити коридор вліво від входу)...
                */
            if ((col - 2) <= 0 || raw == 0)
                continue;
            //якщо елемент, котрий на 2 стопвця лівіше від поточного, рівний 1(стіна)
            if (maze[raw][col - 2] == 1) {
                //то заповнюємо нулями 2 ячейки лабіринту горизонтально вліво від поточної 
                maze[raw][col - 2] = 0;
                maze[raw][col - 1] = 0;
                //викликаємо цю ж функцію для елементу, котрий на 2 стопці лівіше від поточного
                //(тепер він стає поточним)
                recursion(maze, width, height, raw, col - 2);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //ітеруємося елементах з парними індексами(за рахунок того, що будуємо коридори по 2 клітинки,
    //побудова коридору відносно елементу з непарними індексами призведе до злиття коридорів
    //і лабіринт буде мати широкі проходи), причому не враховуємо перші 2 стовпця, останній стовпець (завжди будуть стіни), ,
    //рядок із входом(все одно неможливо буде побудувати ще один коридор відносно входу), рядок нижче(бо непарний індекс), 
    //останній рядок(всі одиниці, поки не згенеруємо вихід)

    for (i = 2; i < height - 1; i += 2) {
        for (j = 2; j < width - 1; j += 2) {
            //якщо елемент 0(прохід) і можно від нього побудувати коридор 
            if (maze[i][j] == 0 && !deadend(maze, width, height, i, j)) {
                //викликаємо для нього функцію
                recursion(maze, width, height, i, j);
                //перериваємо ітерації по матриці
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void showInfo() {
    printf("\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 46);
    puts("                                                                                                                   ");
    puts("                         ##        ##            ##             ##################     ##########                  ");
    puts("                         # #      # #           #  #                           #       #                           ");
    puts("                         #  #    #  #          #    #                        #         #                           ");
    puts("                         #   #  #   #         #      #                     #           #                           ");
    puts("                         #    ##    #        #        #                  #             #                           ");
    puts("                         #          #       ############               #               ##########                  ");
    puts("                         #          #      #            #            #                 #                           ");
    puts("                         #          #     #              #         #                   #                           ");
    puts("                         #          #    #                #      #                     #                           ");
    puts("                         #          #   #                  #    ##################     ##########                  ");
    puts("                                                                                                                   ");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 12);
    puts("                                          --------------------------------------------------");
    puts("                                          |                       HELLO                    |");
    puts("                                          |                                                |");
    puts("                                          |              press G to generate a maze        |");
    puts("                                          |              press E to exit from game         |");
    puts("                                          |                                                |");
    puts("                                          |                                                |");
    puts("                                          --------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n");
}

int executeRequest() {
    showInfo();
    char answer;
    do {
        answer = _getch();
        if (answer == 'G') {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 121);
            puts("                                                                             ");
            puts("     #       #####      ##      ###    #  ##    #  #######                   ");
            puts("     #       #   #     #  #     #  #   #  # #   #  #                         ");
            puts("     #       #   #    ######    #   #  #  #  #  #  #   ###                   ");
            puts("     #       #   #   #      #   #  #   #  #   # #  #     #   ###   ###   ### ");
            puts("     ######  #####  #        #  ###    #  #    ##  #######   ###   ###   ### ");
            puts("                                                                             ");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            animateLoading();
            printf("\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (answer == 'E') {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 31);
            puts("                                                                              ");
            puts("    #######      ##      ##    ##  #####     #####  #        #  #####  #####  ");
            puts("    #           #  #     # #  # #  #         #   #   #      #   #      #   #  ");
            puts("    #   ###    ######    #  ##  #  #####     #   #    #    #    #####  #####  ");
            puts("    #     #   #      #   #      #  #         #   #     #  #     #      # #    ");
            puts("    #######  #        #  #      #  #####     #####      ##      #####  #   #  ");
            puts("                                                                              ");
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 71);
            puts("                                              ");
            puts("         #####  #####  #####  #####  #####    ");
            puts("         #      #   #  #   #  #   #  #   #    ");
            puts("         #####  #####  #####  #   #  #####    ");
            puts("         #      # #    # #    #   #  # #      ");
            puts("         #####  #   #  #   #  #####  #   #    ");
            puts("                                              ");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while (1);
}

void generateMaze() {
    int width, height;
    initDimensions(&width, &height);
    int** maze = provideMemory(width, height);
    initOnes(maze, width, height);
    int entranceX = initEntrance(maze, width, height);
    recursion(maze, width, height, 0, entranceX);
    generateRandExit(maze, width, height);
    printMaze(maze, width, height);
    char answer;
    while (1) {
        puts("Enter 's' to solve maze : ");
        answer = _getch();
        if (answer == 's') {
            solveMaze(maze, width, height, 0, entranceX, 3);
            break;
        }
    }
    cleanMemory(maze, height);

}

void initDimensions(int* widthPointer, int* heightPointer) {
    int askCaseWrongInput = 1;
    do {
        puts("Enter the width of the maze(positive integer greater than 5)");
        scanf_s("%u", widthPointer);
        puts("Enter the height of the maze(positive integer greater than 5)");
        scanf_s("%u", heightPointer);
        if (*widthPointer > 5 && *heightPointer > 5)
        {
            break;
        }
        else {
            puts("\nEnter the correct dimension of the maze, please\n");
        }
    } while (askCaseWrongInput);
}

int** provideMemory(int width, int height) {
    int **maze;
    if ((maze = (int**)calloc(height, sizeof(int*))) == 0) {
        printWarningAndExit();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        if ((maze[i] = (int*)calloc(width, sizeof(int))) == 0) {
            printWarningAndExit();
        }
    }
    return maze;
}

void initOnes(int** maze, int width, int height) {
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int initEntrance(int** maze, int width, int height) {
    int yrandomEntrance;
    //оновлення бази генератора випадкових чисел кожну секунду
    srand(time(NULL));
    //генеруємо випадковий вхід, причому розглядаємо тільки парні індекси
    //не враховуючи крайній лівий і крайній правий елементи
    yrandomEntrance = 2 * (1 + (rand() % ((width - 2) / 2)));
    //initialize the entrance by 0
    maze[0][yrandomEntrance] = 0;
    return yrandomEntrance;
}

void runGame() {
    while (executeRequest()) {
        system("cls");
        generateMaze();

    }
}

void cleanMemory(int **matrix, int height) {
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}

void animateLoading() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sleep(200);
        printf(".");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//todo addresses
int deadend(int** maze, int width, int height, int raw, int col) {
    int a = 0;
    //див. функцію recursion()
    //умови if raw == 0 не перевіряємо, адже у функції recursion() 
    //нульові індекси не будуть розглядатися при ітеруванні по елементах матриці
    if (raw - 2 <= 0 || maze[raw - 2][col] == 0) a++;
    if ((col + 2) >= width - 1 || maze[raw][col + 2] == 0) a++;
    if ((raw + 2) >= height - 1 || maze[raw + 2][col] == 0) a++;
    if ((col - 2) <= 0 || maze[raw][col - 2] == 0) a++;
    if (a == 4) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void generateRandExit(int** maze, int width, int height) {
    //генеруємо вихід(будь-яка ячейка від індексу 2 до передостаннього індексу)
    int randomExit = 2 + rand() % (width - 3);
    maze[height - 1][randomExit] = 0;
    //з'єднуємо вихід з лабіринтом
    //якщо висота представляє собою непарне число, то передостаннім рядком будуть 1
    if (height % 2 == 1) {
        //змінюємо елемент на рядок вище від виходу на 0
        maze[height - 2][randomExit] = 0;
        //піднімаємося ще на рядок, якщо і там 1 то міняємо на 0
        if (maze[height - 3][randomExit] == 1) {
            maze[height - 3][randomExit] = 0;
        }
    }
    //якщо висота представляє собою парне число, то передостаннім рядком можуть бути нулі чи одиниці
    else {
        if (maze[height - 2][randomExit] == 1) {
            maze[height - 2][randomExit] = 0;
        }
    }
}
//1 - up
//2 - left
//3 - down
//4 - right
void solveMaze(int **maze, int width, int height, int raw, int col, int flag) {

    while (1) {
        system("cls");

        maze[raw][col] = 5;

        printMaze(maze, width, height);
        maze[raw][col] = 2;
        Sleep(200);

        if (raw == height - 1)
            break;
        switch (flag)
        {
        case 1:
            if (maze[raw][col - 1] != 1) {
                flag = 2;
                col--;
            }
            else if (maze[raw - 1][col] != 1) {
                flag = 1;
                raw--;
            }

            else if (maze[raw][col + 1] != 1) {
                flag = 4;
                col++;
            }
            else {
                flag = 3;
                raw++;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (maze[raw + 1][col] != 1)
            {
                flag = 3;
                raw++;
            }
            else if (maze[raw][col - 1] != 1)
            {
                flag = 2;
                col--;
            }
            else if (maze[raw - 1][col] != 1)
            {
                flag = 1;
                raw--;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 4;
                col++;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if (maze[raw][col + 1] != 1)
            {
                flag = 4;
                col++;
            }
            else if (maze[raw + 1][col] != 1)
            {
                flag = 3;
                raw++;
            }
            else if (maze[raw][col - 1] != 1)
            {
                flag = 2;
                col--;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
                raw--;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            if (maze[raw - 1][col] != 1)
            {
                flag = 1;
                raw--;
            }
            else if (maze[raw][col + 1] != 1)
            {
                flag = 4;
                col++;
            }
            else if (maze[raw + 1][col] != 1)
            {
                flag = 3;
                raw++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 2;
                col--;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("PATH WAS FOUND");
}
```

Comment: Какая же она локальная, если Вам приходится вручную выделять ей память? Вы должны освобождать всю память, которую запросили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял из кода, освобождать `maze`нужно. так как `maze` указывает на динамическую область памяти в которой содержится указатель который указывает на другую область памяти в которой содержатся массивы. То есть получается матрица. Впрочем вроде бы вы это и делаете.

`int** maze;`  Это статическая переменная и память под нее освободится при выходе из области видимости. Но! она указывает на динамическую область памяти которую нужно освободить.

Comment: спасибо большое. Очень помогли. Подскажите еще, в методе recursion() есть указатель randDirections, по отношению к нему также нужно применять free()?

Comment: @AndreyRafalsky, жизненный цикл каждого calloc/malloc должен в конце концов закончиться вызовом free

Comment: спасибо, разобрался